# JavaScript/jQuery: play sound with loop (each function)

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio

I'm trying to play this same sound with "each function" in jQuery. The array has four elements, for each (after a click function) there's a fadeIn with delay which is working fine; the elements show up one at a time. But I want to play a sound for each element when it appears, and so far I can only hear the sound once. I've searched for similar questions but I couldn't find nothing suitable. How can I achieve this result? The Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var rifle = $('#rifle')[0];
var allTargets=$('#one, #two, #three, #four');
    
allTargets.hide();
   
    $('.start').click(function(){
        $(this).fadeOut();
      
 allTargets.each(function(fadeIn){
     
     $(this).delay(fadeIn * 1000).fadeIn(1000);
        rifle.play(); //Why this sound is triggered only once?
   
    });
    
});
```

Comment: `Why this sound is triggered just once?` - probably triggered as many times as there are elements in allTargets (4?) - just that it's triggered 4 times very very quickly - not after a delay as you may think

Comment: so the problem can be the source of the sound?

Comment: the problem is that  your code, ignoring the animation, is identical to `rifle.play(); rifle.play(); rifle.play(); rifle.play();` - what do you think that would do?

Comment: it makes sense hearing only once becase all 4 are triggered at the same time?

Comment: yes, that's what I've been saying

Comment: ok, so I guess I need a setTimeOut function